# What exactly initialization and loading of asp.net page and its control means?

Tags: asp.net, .net

What is **initialization** of controls and **loading** of the control in *asp.net page life cycle*. I mean what are the memory allocation in these stages

How can we set properties in preinit event even if page has not been initialized.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

I don't know why memory allocation is so impotent to you but I believed that Microsoft decided to manage it in .Net framework itself(you can neither really see if nor change it) not just for not generate problem like C++ will do but also for free us out off worried about that, if your application really worried about memory then I don't think .Net is a good choice for you, nor java btw.

Comment: thanks for response but i just wanted to know how memory get used while page life cycle execution.